# How to edit escaped HTML?

Tags: html

Is there a way to edit escaped HTML as literal HTML within a HTML document?

E.g instead of seeing/editing this in my emacs buffer:

```html
<div>
    <code>
        &lt;p&gt;some &lt;em&gt;html&lt;/em&gt; here&lt;/p&gt;
    </code>
</div>
```

I'd instead be seeing/editing the following:

```html
<div>
    <code>
        <p>some <em>html</em> here</p>
    </code>
</div>
```

with everything inside the code element actually being saved (or copied to the clipboard) as escaped.

The escaped HTML should probably show itself in another color scheme so one would know that it's actually escaped.

Perhaps there is some common mechanism for this encoder/decoder system -- similar to how for links only the label is shown and the URL is hidden?